# How to set UITableView contentinset and insert row at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uianimation

I am trying to add a row to the top of my tableview at -44.0 offset (hidden) and not see any animations on the screen. To do this I am calling

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

and

```
UIEdgeInsets ins = self.tableView.contentInset;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44.0, ins.left, ins.bottom, ins.right);
```

The problem is that this moves the tableview up because of setting the offset, then it animates back down due to adding the row.

I want my existing tableview to look like it did not move, and just add the new row at the top (hidden) without anyone seeing anything.

Anybody know how I can add the row to the top in the background?

Thanks!